# [Word Game]Quiddler Solver Algorithm

Tags: c++, python, c, algorithm

### Quiddler Solver

I have a card game called Quiddler that I'm trying to write an algorithm to solve, but when I try and solve it linearly its very slow and inefficient.

**The Game (Step by step):**

1. Each player is dealt a number of cards between 3 and 10, each card has either one or two letters on it.
2. The player then tries to make a single or multiple words from the cards they are given, without having excess cards.

While I tried my best at an algorithm to preform these seeming easy tasks it takes over 20 seconds to find all the answers for even a medium length hand.

I used a dictionary [such as this one](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/share/dict/web2?rev=1.12;content-type=text%2Fplain) for my wordlist.  I linearly check  the number of letters in my hand and I compare it to the words in the list assuming they are of equal or shorter length.  While this works it takes far too long.

I hope somebody can help me out here, preferably in Perl, Python, or C/C++.

**Example Hand:**
cards=['i','d','o','n']

**Answers(According to my algorithm):**
di no,
di on,
do in,
id no,
id on,
in do,
in od,
dino,
nodi

### My Algorithm in Python:

```
import timeit
from wordlist import *
#Quiddler Solver
print 'Dictionary loaded\n'

#Define our hand
cards=['i','d','o','n']

#Count the letters in a word
def cntLetters(word):   #Surely there's a better way?
    lettercnt={97:0,98:0,99:0,100:0,101:0,102:0,103:0,104:0,105:0,106:0,107:0,108:0,109:0,110:0,111:0,112:0,113:0,114:0,115:0,116:0,117:0,118:0,119:0,120:0,121:0,122:0}
    for v in word:
        lettercnt[ord(v)]+=1
    return lettercnt

#Check the letters to make sure our hand has at least what the word has
def cmpList(list1,list2):
    for k,v in list1.iteritems():
        if list2[k]<=v:
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

#Check to make sure cards with more than one letter are together in the word.
def has(word):
    for v in cards:
        if len(v)>1:
            if v in word:
                pass
            else:
                return False
    return True

def solve():
    rawhand=''.join(cards).lower()
    hand=cntLetters(rawhand)
    handl=len(rawhand)
    buff=[]
    for v in dict:  #Add all words that have at least the letters in our hand to buff
        if len(v)<=handl and cmpList(hand,cntLetters(v)):
            if has(v):
                buff.append(v)
    for v in range(0,int((len(buff)/2)+1)): #Find 2 words that can be used together to make a play
        for n in buff:
            if len(n)==(handl-len(buff[v])):
                if hand==cntLetters(buff[v]+n):
                    print buff[v],n
    for v in range(0,int((len(buff)/3)+1)): #This is a bit overkill since it finds so much stuff, need to tune it
        for n in buff:
            if (len(n))<=len(buff[v]):
                for x in buff:
                    if len(x)==(handl-len(buff[v])-len(n)):
                        if hand==cntLetters(buff[v]+n+x):
                            print buff[v],n,x
    for v in buff:  #Print the single words that can be made
        if len(v)==handl:
            print v

t = timeit.Timer(stmt=solve)
print 'Search took %.2f seconds'%t.timeit(number=1)
```

*I import a precompiled list of the words called dict from wordlist.*

I hope somebody can help me out with my algorithm design because it needs improvement, thanks.

Somebody suggested using a DAWG, but I'm not doing any word lookups.  In which case I still have to cycle the words to check the letters, unless I'm thinking along the wrong lines?

Comment: Can I get a hint specifically on the last part when I'm finding the word sets that can be used with each other in a hand.  It takes forever to find 3 words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try storing the word list as a [directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) (DAWG) or a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for fast lookups.

Place the first letter and use the DAWG/trie to find out all the possibilities for the second letter, and so on. Use backtracking when no more letters can be placed, or when a solution has been found and you want the next one.

This algorithm should be roughly linear in the number of solutions, and if written efficiently should be able to solve your problem in a few milliseconds for 10 cards. Note though that the number of solutions grows rapidly as you add more cards.

Comment: Purely speaking of performance would it be faster to use a DAWG or a Trie? I'm trying to implement this right now.

Comment: @Nowayz: From Wikipedia: *[A DAWG] allows for a query operation that tests whether a given string belongs to the set in time proportional to its length. In these respects, a DAWG is very similar to a trie, but it is much more space efficient.* A trie would work too though.

Comment: Yes, but building the DAWG is a lot more expensive than building a trie. It can be done off-line, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: A trie actually is a special case of a DAWG - it's simpler to implement but less space-efficient. Regarding time-efficiency, it shouldn't make a huge difference which you pick as long as you have enough memory to store the entire structure in RAM.

Comment: Maybe you know a better way to build DAWGs than me. I start by building a trie and then merge isomorphic nodes.

Comment: How am I supposed to use a DAWG in this context, I'm never looking up a word, I'm searching for anagrams basically.  I count the letters in the word to find other words with similar letters.  I don't see how this can boost the performance.

Comment: @Nowayz: Construct the words one at a time using the letters you have remaining, traversing the trie as you go and backtracking if you reach a dead end. You never need to count anything - you can construct the solutions directly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very straightforward reduction from your problem to set cover, which is NP-complete, so while you may be able to make minor improvements using DAWGs there is no known efficient solution.